# Math.log, a Natural logarithmic y scale for currency time-series?

Tags: javascript, arrays, math

My attempts to make my *y* values scale to logarithmic are turning my data upside-down.

I have vanilla js code and every implementation I read about are tied up in huge libraries of production code, I am not sure how/what to extract, I need some guidance as I could not put my finger on the problem weather it be sum or miss-use of the Math functions.

I am testing this by drawing the *y* 'data' to canvas (no libraries used) my *x* axis is constant 2px difference

Math.log uses **e** (2.718) as default base which is what I have read.. So I should be seeing my price data on a natural log scale but it wont work.

```
function logScale(data){
    var log=data.slice(0);
    var i=log.length;
    while(i--){

        log[i]=Math.log(data[i]); // should be natural but I don't see a change

        // log[i]=Math.pow(Math.log(data[i]),10); //upside-down

        // log[i]=Math.log(data[i])/Math.LN10;  //no visible change when drawn to canvas


        }
    console.dir(log);
    return log;
    }
```

Another attempt from a couple of weeks ago where I am using the data min, max and difference. then removing all the infinity.

```
function ᐥlogarithm(data){
    var Lmax,Lmin,Ldif,Logarithm,infinity;
    Lmax=Math.max.apply(this,data);
    Lmin=Math.min.apply(this,data);
    Ldif=(Lmax-Lmin);
    Logarithm=[];
    infinity=[];
    for(var i=data.length-1;i>=0;i--){
        Logarithm[i]=Math.log((data[i]-Lmin)/Ldif);
        if(Logarithm[i]===-Infinity){infinity.push(i);}
        }
    for(var i=0;i<=infinity.length-1;i++){Logarithm.splice(infinity[i],1);}
    return Logarithm;
    }
```

The data looks different but still not quite like log scale. **It is vertically warped** to best describe it.

Please note jsfiddle-ing this won't work as The data is bitcoin prices (real time) so as there is no working code for a log scale there is no good way to show a comparison. Bitcoin or any other exchange data gets served as is so these functions would (if they worked) transfom *any* data array to log scale.

How do D3 do it? What is wrong with my code?

Comment: What does not work? Your `logScale` function behaves like I would expect. You could shorten it to `function logScale(data){ return data.map(Math.log); }`, though.

Comment: It does not make the the chart look like the bitcoin charts on all the exchanges (they are log charts) my chart still looks like raw data

Comment: Well, that is probably of problem of the code you use to draw the chart.

Comment: can't be because the code to draw is the same if i draw linear. what I am saying is that the data values are no higher or lower to look like a log scale

Comment: Can you change your code to use some static example test data instead of dynamic real time data? Then fiddle that? Without anything to look at, it's very hard to guess where this problem might lie, if it's even in the code snippets you pasted.

Comment: should I be drawing different? to normalistion (min,max,difference)

`ctx.lineTo(x,(((data[i]-min)/difference)*100)+top);`

Comment: @BenMuircroft add image of your in/out and desired output

Comment: You need better variable names.  `log`, `infinity`, and `Logarithm` are all arrays?!

Comment: FWIW, it is sometimes the case that the label **log-scale** implicitly involves log of the _ratios_ between adjacent entries, rather than log of the entries themselves, although I'm not familiar with the bitcoin charts themselves.